# How to include vbs code in Windows Task Scheduler?

Tags: vbscript

Currently I am including a `vbs` code to the `Windows Task Scheduler` using a `. vbs` file like this

```
 <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>cscript</Command>
      <Arguments>"c:\users\owner\desktop\test.vbs"</Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
```

It works fine. This makes a reference to the file. It is similar to running a `vbs` from a `command line`

`cscript "c:\users\owner\desktop\test.vbs`

---

Is there any way of writing the `vbs` directly to the windows task scheduler  without keeping a `test.vbs` file on the drive ?

I tried this

```
<Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>cscript</Command>
      <Arguments>"msgbox ""hi"""</Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
```

And it did not work.
Is there any way to write vbs directly to the command line ?

Comment: `cscript.exe` isn't meant to receive code from input or anything like that. The script file must exist.

Comment: `cscript.exe` & `wscript.exe` are designed to execute scripts just like any other .exe file (but you can write one to do it). By the way, you should **NOT** Task Schedule a script with that user path!